# Unpack a list so the first element is assigned the result of a function operated on the following elements

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list where I'd like to extract its elements so that the first element extracted is assigned the result of a function operated on the following elements.
That is to say, given the list `["user_arr", 100, True]` I'd like the end result to be: `user_arr = prev_def_func(100, True)`.

Thanks in advance.

***P.S.*** I've already been answered that this is not a viable design, but, because I was asked and so as to let others know it's not a good design, the reason for the question is I had a function I needed to call several times in repetition, each time with another set of arguments:

```
user_in1 = prev_func(val1, flag1)
user_in2 = prev_func(val2, flag2)
and so on...
```

I thought I'd zip all the arguments (e.g. user_inX, valX, flagX) into a list of lists then iterate over the nested list, calling each sub-list's elements in the fashion listed above.

Comment: `l[0] = prev_def_func(*l[1:])`? But it's not clear why you'd want this or what you're trying to achieve; could you give a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: If you need to access a variable by a name stored in a string, you probably should redesign.

Comment: Oh, I think I see, I thought you wanted the result *in* the list. If you think you want to use the string as a name, think again.

Comment: So, not the best of designs? Fair enough. Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it might not be good idea to create variable names from strings but it's definitely possible.

```
i = ["user_arr", 100, True]
locals()[i[0]] = prev_def_func(*i[1:])
print(user_arr)
```

However, using a dict feels cleaner and idiomatic.

```
i = ["user_arr", 100, True]
o = {i[0]: prev_def_func(*i[1:])}
print(o["user_arr"])
```

**Update after seeing you PS**

You should definitely use a dict.

```
arg_list = [(user_in1, val1, flag1), ...]
result = {user_in: prev_def_func(val, flag) for user_in, val, flag in arg_list}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `o = {i[0]: prev_def_func(*i[1:])}`, that is the slice is from element indexed 1 and on? Tried it with the slice like that and it worked like charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Note a very good design and only work with the globals variable of a module:

```
very_strange_list = [
    ["user_arr", 100, True],
    ["user_arr2", 500, False],
]

def my_func(val1, val2):
    return '%d %s' % (val1, val2)

for data in very_strange_list:
    globals()[data[0]] = my_func(*data[1:])
```

data[1:] will create a new list with elements 1 to the end of your list.
The unary * will extract each field from the list and assign it to the function parameters.

globals() while return a dictionary of the global symbol table of the current module. (If in a function or a method, where the function is defined, not where it's used)

Solution with locals() **doesn't work**, the documentation say explicitly to not modify the dictionary:

> Note: The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Didn't even know about `locals()` and `globals()` before. Changed my design to use dictionary instead.